# Multicast stream to unicast stream tcl script questions

Tags: eclipse-plugin, tcl, tk-toolkit, tclsh

I'm starting to learn tcl script language, and I was trying to do a tcl script that tunnels all the multicast packets across a unicast network.

Since I'm newcomer concerning to tcl, I would like to ask to points:

1. I'm using Eclipse to code in tcl, I have installed the needed plug-in and I think also all the packages, however, Eclipse underlines me the following call

   ```
   fconfigure $sockMulticast -buffering none -mcastadd $ipMulticast -translation binary -remote [list $ipMulticast $port]
   ```

   Saying that there is extra arguments, which I don't understand since [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8493) it can be read:

   > Pat has written, "Multicast is a little different to standard unicast
   >   or broadcast UDP. Your operating system ignores multicast packets
   >   unless an application has explicitly joined a multicast group. In the
   >   case of TclUDP we do this by using
   >
   > ```
   > fconfigure $socket -mcastadd $mcastaddress
   > ```
2. When I configure the TCP socket, the unicast one, should I specify again the destination unicast IP again when invoking `fconfigure`?

### Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# updToTcp.tcl \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}

package require udp

set ::connectionsMulticast [list]
set ::connectionsUnicast [list]

proc udp_connect {ipMulticast ipUnicast port {multicast false}} {

    #Open UDP multicast socket
    set sockMulticast [udp_open $port]  
    if {$multicast} {
        #configures the multicast port
        fconfigure $sockMulticast -buffering none -mcastadd $ipMulticast -translation binary -remote [list $ipMulticast $port] ;#(1)
        #update the list of multicast connections with the socket
        lappend ::connectionsMulticast[list $ipMulticast $port $socketMulticast]

        #Open TCP unicast socket
        set sockUnicast [socket $ipUnicast $port]
        #configures the unicast port
        fconfigure $sockUnicast -buffering none -translation binary;#(2)
        #update the list of unicast connections with the socket
        lappend ::connectionsMulticast[list $ipUnicast $port $socketUnicast]

        #listen to the multicast socket, and forwarding the data to the unicast one
        fileevent $sockMulticast readable [list ::dataForwarding $sockMulticast $sockUnicast]
    }
}

    proc dataForwarding {socketSrc socketDst} {
    #get the data from the source socket, and place it on data
    set data [read $socketSrc]
    #placing the data in the destination socket
    puts -nonewline $socketDst $data
    return
    }
```

Comment: You're generally recommended to ask only one question per question; it's easier to get searchability working for that.

Answer (score 1):

On the first point, **Eclipse is plain wrong**. The `fconfigure` command can take any number of option/value pairs (or a single option to retrieve a value, or no options to retrieve many values at once — though not *necessarily* all; serial channels have some odd features, but they don't matter to you at the moment). It's unfortunate that they're wrong, but it happens.

On the second point, I would not try to change the IP address of a TCP endpoint; you can't do that (strictly, not with Tcl's binding; I've no idea at all if you can do so in general). TCP and UDP channels have very different restrictions on what can be changed and when (because TCP channels use a handshake protocol to build a connected session between two ports, whereas UDP has no such restriction at all; in return, TCP channels can be regarded as reliable streams, whereas UDP is not a streaming protocol at all and has no sessions/connections).

You also have a problem with your `lappend` calls; you're omitting a crucial space between the variable name and the value to append to those global lists. This will mean that the global variables that you *expect* to hold the lists of connection information will not actually be doing so; instead you'll get lots of strange variables with wholly impractical names. And it will all totally break if you add IPv6 support (as that can use `::` in the rendering of IP addresses, despite it also being a Tcl namespace separator). Fix it now; save yourself a bit of trouble in the future...

Comment: I should warn that I don't use TclUDP in my own projects; I don't need typically to. (Those projects tend to run in very different directions to yours…)

Comment: OK, I won't pay attention to eclipse syntax and fconfigure... Concerning to the second point,how can I tunnel the multicast traffic to unicast one? Should I always use UDP, for instance? I mean, tunnel the UDP multicast traffic over a UDP unicast socket, would that be a better option?